# "Don't hold me against your decision"—grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

There's a fairly common expression: "Don't hold it against them", meaning "Don't blame them for what has happened".

But does this exact phrase make sense: "Don't hold me against your decision"?

**Context**

The other day I didn't do something that I wanted to do, because I knew it would annoy my friend. Talking about it later, she said I should have done it, and "don't hold me against your decision".

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatically, the request should have been the other way around - for you to not hold *your decision* against *her*.

> **Hold something against someone** *idiom*
>   Allow past actions or circumstances to have a negative influence on one’s present attitude towards someone: *if he failed her, she would hold it against him forever*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hold-something-against-someone?q=hold%20against)